# Difference between these combinatorics questions?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

You are stopping by Timmy’s to buy two dozen donuts. There are 6 varieties to choose from and you
need to have at least one donut from each variety. How many different ways can you select your two
dozen donuts?

here we use stars and bars to arrive at 33, 649

but here

You have 8 colours of paint and 14 rooms in your house, each of which you want to paint in a single colour.
Q: How many ways can you paint your house?
8^14

so we are also looking for the amount of ways but don't use stars and bars? So can someone illustrate the difference?

Answer (score 3):

For the first, donuts of a given type are indistinguishable.  All you care about is how many you get of each type.  Stars and bars places dividers between the types.  For the second the rooms are different, so painting the first room red and second blue is different from painting the first blue and the second red.  You have eight choices of color for each room, so use the multiplication principle.

Comment: would you say select is an important word for distinguishing the two? or no

Comment: I think you need to consider each question carefully, not focusing on whether a particular word is in the problem or not.  Problems can be stated many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another two questions:

**Question 1:** How many ways are there of putting $6$ plain (indistinguishable) balls into $4$ numbered (distinguishable) boxes?

Answer is $\binom{4+6-1}{3} = \binom{9}{3} = 84$ by stars and bars (I didn't know what it is called). It is the same thing but you can also think of it as a binary string of $1$'s and $0$'s. For example if you put $1$ ball to first box, $3$ balls to second box, $1$ balls to third box and $1$ ball to fourth box, you have a binary string like "$010001010$" (Here $1$'s are seperating the boxes). So the question is as same as how many ways are there of constructing a binary string with three $1$'s and six $0$'s.

**Question 2:** How many ways are there of putting $6$ colored (now distinguishable) balls into $4$ numbered (distinguishable) boxes?

Answer is $4^6 = 4096$ by counting.

Comment: Hmmm I have another question... Your local grocery store just received a large shipment of apples, oranges, pears, and bananas—more 
than 100 pieces each. You are shopping at the store and will purchase your fruit for the week.
How many ways can you select 10 pieces of fruit from your store’s supply of apples, oranges, pears,
and bananas, if you need at least 2 oranges and 1 apple? here stars and bars right.. but are the fruits are distinguishable no? like an orange is not an apple..

Comment: Actually in this one, you may need to use generating functions.

Comment: from the solution you can use both

Comment: Yes, fruits are distinguishable but not in themselves, that is, two apples are indistinguishable. In this case, if you consider fruits (apple, orange, pear, banana) as numbered boxes (so there are $4$ of them) and pieces as plain balls (we have $10$ pieces), you can solve it with stars and bars.